# CASE statement not working with date part

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am comparing date if it is greater than 17:00:00 then it should return Evening else morning if > than 17:00:00. I am trying with CASE but gives error on > < signs , why ?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_Report_SelectComplaintsByShift] 

    @IsMorningEvening bit

AS
BEGIN

    Begin Try

      Select ComplaintID, ComplaintSubject, Complainants.ComplainantName as Complainant
      CASE
      Complaints.ClosingDateTime
      When (Complaints.ClosingDateTime  < '17:00:00') then 'Morning'
      When (Complaints.ClosingDateTime > '17:00:00') then 'Evening'
      End as ClosingShift
      from Complaints Inner Join Complainants 
      ON Complaints.Complainant_ID = Complainants.ComplainantID

END
```

Comment: You are comparing a DateTime value to a string which represents a time. What do you expect to get here as a result? Take a look at the `DATEPART` function.

Comment: The direct answer to "why?" is ["because your syntax is wrong"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx "CASE (Transact-SQL)"). You are mixing a simple CASE with a searched CASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extract the `hour` instead using `datepart()`:

```
  Select ComplaintID, ComplaintSubject, Complainants.ComplainantName as Complainant
         (case When (datepart(hour, Complaints.ClosingDateTime) < 17) then 'Morning'
               else 'Evening'
          End) as ClosingShift
  from Complaints Inner Join
       Complainants 
       on Complaints.Complainant_ID = Complainants.ComplainantID;
```